# Problem with installing Nvidia driver 319

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates

I have Ubuntu ver. 12.04 and Nvidia ver. 304. After i updated my driver to 319 which is recommended in Additional Driver, I got stuck in the booting screen with something like: AppArmor etc. (black screen with yellow code) so i had to reinstall my OS.

Please could you help me how to install it correctly without error, because I am new with Linux.

Thank you very much!